# After cloning Xamarin documentation from Git repo, how can I browse it locally?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I need access to the complete Xamarin documentation locally considering the fact that the one provided through Visual Studio Help Viewer is incomplete and unpleasant to the eyes when browsing through its interface.

After cloning the one from https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/xamarin-docs I'm now interested in how could I open it in the same manner when I'm browsing it online; (I see all kinds of files like .yml etc.) ?

Thanks.

Comment: the docs themselves are written in Markdown, so use any markdown capable editor or viewer.  You can get Markdown extensions for most common browsers

Comment: @Jason Thx. Regards.

Comment: Did you solve your issue? If so,please post your solution as an answer and accept it so this questions gets marked as answered. Helps other searching for questions to help on so they don't waste time on questions that are answered.